# Defining Positive integers..

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, definition

While reading Calculus by Apostol I  found the set of positive integers defined as "Set of Real numbers that belong to every Inductive set"...

The question is "Why we don't define the set of 1,1+1,1+1+1,...
I mean all such numbers as the set of positive integers?"

He has said that this will not define the set completely and so we use  "Inductive sets"

but can someone please explain it a bit more so it becomes actually clear to use inductive sets to define them..

Comment: Before you have natural numbers, how do you iteratively define object? Definition like $1+\dotsb+1$ only makes sense if you already have natural numbers and want to embed they into some ring.

Comment: I mean he has defined others in terms of the number 1

Comment: You can define *a* number using $1$, sure. But you can't define *infinitely many numbers* using $1$. You could, however, argue that the positive integers is the smallest set which contains $1$ and closed under addition. This would be in the spirit of what you suggest. But there is a huge problem with using "..." in a rudimentary definition, since it leaves room for interpretation, and at this point it's not clear if the reader can guess the right interpretation. So if you want to be accurate, you need to just be accurate.

Comment: Isn' t  it a little superfluous a bit fancy it actually appears clear to me even when i use "..." or "and so on" it is really hard to get why it is so strict

Comment: @AsafKaragila sure you can define an infinitely many numbers using 1.  "A postitve numbers is either 1 or the sum of a positive number and 1"

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, what does "all such numbers" actually mean?  You can write down any single number like $1+1$ or $1+1+1+1+1$ easily, but how can you say exactly what the set of all of them is?  You need to define what it means for a number to be "a sum of some number of copies of $1$", but how can you do that when you don't know what "number" (which in the context of this phrase would mean a positive integer number) means?  In order to rigorously prove things about the natural numbers, you will need a completely precise definition of what they are.  And it is quite difficult to say precisely what you mean by "all such numbers" in a non-circular way.  So you need to find a more precise way of defining the natural numbers, and that is the purpose of the definition using inductive sets.

Comment: What's wrong with using the Peano axioms as your definition of natural number?

Comment: Nothing, though in this context the natural numbers are being defined in terms of an axiomatization of the real numbers, so it would be kind of redundant to also axiomatize the natural numbers.

Answer (score -1):

For discrete mathematics the natural numbers (which is practically the same as positive integers without zero) is typically defined using 0 and the successor function S (the successor function being the same +1) $ x \in \mathbb{N} \iff x = 0 \lor \exists y \in \mathbb{N} : S(y)=x $.

Which is effectively the same definition you used so the claim that there exist positive integers that are not covered by that definition runs counter to the standard use of the term "Positive Integer".

Comment: What is asked is that if 1 is assumed to be a real no. Then can we define the numbers like 1,1+1,1+1 and so on...as positive integers without any use of inductive sets whereas the book says strictly that this approach is somehow not rigorous...i do'nt get it..